# Set public variables node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to access to a variable that i define in my index.js from static.js which is called with require()

Index.js

```
function API() {
    var self = this
    self.init = function(apikey, region, locale) {
        //Some stuff
        self.region = region
        self.locale = locale
        self.apikey = apikey

        self.static = require('./static').static

    }

}
module.exports = new API();
```

Static.js

```
module.exports = {
    static: {
        someFunction: function(someParameters) {
            //Need to access to self.region, self.locale and self.apikey
        },
        otherFunction: function(someParameters) {
            //Need to access to self.region, self.locale and self.apikey
        }
    }
```

My problem is to use region, locale and apikey from the static.js file

Test.js
    var api = require('./index.js');

```
api.init('myKey', 'euw', 'en_US')
console.log(api);
```

does that:

```
RiotAPI {
    region: 'euw',
    locale: 'en_US',
    apikey: 'myKey',
    static: { someFunction: [Function], otherFunction: [Function] }
}
```

which is okay but when i call someFunction() with the good arguments it tells me that self.region (and the others i guess) is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the methods from static.js at the top-level of your API instance.

```
var static = require('./static').static
function API() {
    // constructor
}

API.prototype.init = function(apikey, region, locale) {
    //Some stuff
    this.region = region
    this.locale = locale
    this.apikey = apiKey
}
Object.assign(API.prototype, static)
module.exports = new API();
```

Then reference `this.region` etc. in your static methods.

Comment: Why not just use `Object.assign()` to copy properties from one object to another?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, you can also do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've edited my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: @jfriend00  I edit the question to specify my problem which is how to referen this.region in static methods ?